# How to validate objectID by using the joiful packge

Tags: typescript, joi

I'm using joiful package for my validations.so my case I've to validate the objectID. so, I tried like this but it doesn't work out. Any suggestions?

```
// ObjectID Validation
export const ObjectID = (required: boolean = false) => {
    const jfFunction = jf.string().valid(ObjectID)
    if (required) {
        return _required(jfFunction);
    }
    return jfFunction;
};
```